# Rails render partial as widget over ajax using jsonp

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, jsonp

I've looked at quite a few other answers on here, but I'm still struggling a bit to figure out how to set up my Rails widget.

I have this code in my widget controller:

```
  def widget
    status = Company.friendly.find(params[:id]).widget.active
    body = to_json_value(render_to_string('companies/_widget', locals: { profile: self.profile }))

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: { status: status, html: body }, callback: params[:callback] }
    end
  end

  private

  def to_json_value(str)
    str.gsub!("\"", "\\\"")
    str.gsub!(/\n+/, " ")
    str
  end
```

The `self.profile` method just sets up a list of variables that get passed to the partial.

What I want to do is give a user a Javascript script tag that they can embed on their (external) website. When a user hits that page, the script will make an AJAX call to the widget controller and if the widget is turned on, it will receive a string of html to be rendered on the page.

So far I've got the widget controller to return a json object with the status and the html string. The problem is when I paste the localhost url into jsonlint.com, it says it is invalid. This is also confirmed when I insert a script tag into an html file and then open it in Chrome. I get an error saying there was an `unexpected token :`. So I then changed my controller and widget.js.erb to include a callback function. I added `, callback: params[:callback]` to my controller.

I also set up a callback function (doesn't do anything yet) in my widget.js.erb file. I then embed this file using a script tag in an html file and load that in Chrome. When I do, I get an error saying that `showWidget` is undefined.

I'm struggling to find resources that explain how to load data over jsonp from a rails app, and how callback functions come into play.

Here is my widget.js.erb:

```
function showWidget();

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/<%= params[:company] %>/widget?callback=?',
  jsonpCallback: 'showWidget',
  contentType: "application/json",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'JSONP',
  success: function (data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#company-widget').html(result.html);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
});
```

Here is my test.html:

```
<div id="company-widget"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/taco-corp/widget.js?callback=showWidget" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm also not sure where this widget.js.erb script should live in my rails app. Here is what I have so far for my widget.js.erb:

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I needed to add a callback to my rails controller and to my $.ajax method. I didn't have the callback set up correctly in my ajax call. I also needed to specify the correct header (contentType) to get around an HTTP 406 error. Here is the working jQuery code below for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var company = 'taco-corp';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/' + company + '/widget.js?callback=?',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#company-widget').html(data.html);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my rails controller:

```
  def widget
    status = Company.friendly.find(params[:id]).widget.active

    body = render_to_string('companies/_widget', layout: false, locals: { profile: self.profile })

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: { status: status, html: body }, callback: params[:callback] }
    end
  end
```